# Exit a Ruby script with status 0 on an exception

Tags: ruby

I'm currently wrapping scripts with `begin; rescue; end`. Which works, but is annoying to un/comment at two different places and so on. Is there something like `error_reporting(0);` in PHP, but applied to the exit code and STDERR output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try trapping the [EXIT signal](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Signal.html#method-c-trap):

> The special signal name "EXIT" or signal number zero will be invoked just prior to program termination.

Something like this should guarantee that your script always returns zero to the operating system:

```
Signal.trap('EXIT') { exit 0 }
```

For example, this script:

```
Signal.trap('EXIT') { exit 0 }
exit 1
```

actually returns zero to the OS despite triggering script's termination with `exit 1`.

Answer (score -1):

Actually I did not understand what you are asking for. Here is the answer as I understand. But would be useful if you provide some more detail.

```
def
  some code...
rescue
  abort
end
```

Comment: `abort` does an `exit(false)` but OP is asking for the opposite, so instead of abort you may want to call `exit` or the more explicit `exit(true)`.